# How to return a list of strings using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have in my database 3 rows, Nome,Curso,Periodo, and i want to create a method who will return a list of strings using LINQ, i'm new to using LINQ, i found something like that,but how to use like list os strings?

```
IQueryable<Customer> custQuery =
from cust in db.Customers
where cust.City == "London"
select cust;
```

Comment: What kind of strings do you expect in your list? Currently you return a list (actually `IQueyable`) of `Customer`. If your `Customer` contains the strings you need, then you can select them instead of whole object

Comment: this is just a example that i found,i want to know how to create this method and return `Nome,Curso,Periodo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to combine all properties to single string, you can concatenate them in select statment. Also, use method `ToList()` to convert result to `List` instead of `IQueryable`. Below code should work fine, if all 3 of the properties are of string type:

```
List<string> custQuery =
    (from cust in db.Customers
    where cust.City == "London"
    select cust.Nome + "," + cust.Curso + "," + cust.Periodo).ToList();
```

Comment: i get it,so how will be my Method? public list<string> name....?something like that?

Comment: @NathielPaulino Your method signature would be `public List<string> MethodName() { ... }`

Comment: hi, if i  don't want to combine all properties to single string,and yes list each one like
`Orange`
`Apple`
`Blue` and not Orange,Apple,Blue!

Comment: @NathielPaulino Then use space instead of comma

Answer (score 0):

the result you get is IEnumerable. you can do something like:

```
            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            foreach (Customers cust in db.Customers)
                list.Add(cust.City);
```